# AES-256-ECB encryption in nodejs does not match php MCrypt module

Tags: php, node.js, encryption, mcrypt

I'm receiving an encrypted message from an external party. They're using php and `mcrypt` for encryption with the following configuration

- algo: rijndael-256
- mode: ecb
- example encrypted message: `"a364cb3bb55c2788b25f04ef6867d770771a7d0fdd44462b40233ea76a8bd00d"`. Its original message is `"thank you"`

The following images showing the configuration
[image]

From my side, I'm using nodejs to decrypt. I have a working version with [node-mcrypt binding](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mcrypt). But I want to avoid native modules so I'm looking for a pure javascript solution.

I tried node's `crypto` but its `aes-256-ecb` produces different (unreadable) output

The working code with MCrypt binding in nodejs:

```
const decryptAES256 = (encrypted: string, password: string): string => {
  try {
    const desEcb = new MCrypt('rijndael-256', 'ecb');
    desEcb.open(md5(password));
    const ciphertext = desEcb.decrypt(new Buffer(encrypted, 'hex'));
    const plain = ciphertext.toString();

    const isUTF8 = plain.split('').every(c => c.charCodeAt(0) <= 256);

    if (!isUTF8) {
      throw new Error('Invalid Input');
    }

    const unpadding = plain
      .split('')
      .filter(c => c.charCodeAt(0))
      .join('');

    return unpadding;
  } catch (ex) {
    console.error('Invalid token');
  }
};
```

Comment: Ideally, just don't use mcrypt, any version or binding to it. But your question is still rather short on specifics and code, take a look at [ask]

Comment: Don't use ECB: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/why-shouldnt-i-use-ecb-encryption

Comment: When you state "rijndael-256" that maybe specifying a 256-bit block size which is not AES. AES has one block size: 128-bits, But **where is the code**?

Comment: Do not use ECB mode in new work and update legacy work ASAP, it is not secure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: It is best not to use PHP mcrypt, it is abandonware, has not been updated in years and does not support standard PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding, only non-standard null padding that can't even be used with binary data. mcrypt has many outstanding [bugs](https://sourceforge.net/p/mcrypt/bugs/) dating back to 2003. The mcrypt-extension is deprecated will be removed in PHP 7.2. Instead consider using [defuse](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption) or [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor), they provide a complete solution and are being maintained and is correct.

Comment: Because I'm receiving the encrypted data from a 3rd party service, I can't change the encryption mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After realizing that rijndael 256 is not equivalent to aes 256 (with 128 version is), I opt to find a rijndael specific lib in pure javascript and this is a working code:

```
const Rijndael = require('rijndael-js');

describe('cipher', () => {
  it('should work', () => {
    const text = 'thank you';
    //  + String.fromCharCode(0).repeat(5)
    const key = '94a08da1fecbb6e8b46990538c7b50b2';
    const cipher = new Rijndael(key, 'ecb');
    const ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(text, 256);

    expect(ciphertext.toString('hex')).toBe(
      'a364cb3bb55c2788b25f04ef6867d770771a7d0fdd44462b40233ea76a8bd00d'
    );

    const plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext, 256);
    const unpadded = plaintext.toString().replace(/\u0000*$/g, '');
    expect(unpadded).toBe(text);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

When you state "rijndael-256" that maybe specifying a 256-bit block size which is not AES. AES has one block size: 128-bits.

This seems to be born out by the encrypted output which is 32-binary bytes and for an input of "thank you" the output should be one block so it seems the block size is 32-bytes (256-bits).

1. Do not use mcrypt, it will just cause interoperability problems.
2. Make sure you are using AES which can be rijndael with a 128-bit block size.
3. Do not confuse the key size with the block size.
4. If the input data is not always a multiple of the block size then padding must be added to the input data], specify padding, PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding which may be the default. mcrypt does not support standard padding. If you must interoperate with mcrypt you will need to specify no padding and perform the padding yourself.

Comment: thank you for clarify the difference between rijndael and aes. Without this I would still be trying crypto/openssl's `aes-256-ecb`